# Difference between scenario and scenaio out line

Tags: karate

i have created below feature and calling this in another feature file

@ignore
Feature: re-usable feature to create a single order

Scenario Outline: Create multiple users and verify their id, name and age

Given url 'https://arid-stage.****/sun-api//user/****'

And request { locale:'',offerId:'',operationType:'',paidTermDuration:'',paidTermDurationUnit:'',paymentCategory:'',storeOrderId:'',userId:'' }
When method post
Then status 200

Examples:
    | locale  | offerId | operationType| paidTermDuration |paidTermDurationUnit | paymentCategory |storeOrderId|userId  |
    | en_us    | 7777777      | CREATE       | 30       |      MONTH        | VENDOR_PAYMENT          | localDate  | 42DC198E5ABCE1430A494128  |

In other feature, i'm calling feature -> * def result = call read('redeem-create.feature')

Questions:
This will be executed only when with text **Scenario Outline** and i remove and update as Scenario, this will not get executed.

When to use scenario outline and scenario

Any suggestions/ ideas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you read the documentation: https://github.com/intuit/karate#data-driven-tests

And also look at this example for a comparison: [`examples.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/demo/outline/examples.feature)

Comment: Thanks Peter. I have resolved it. What i understand is testing single feature with multiple test data , in that use case..having scenari out line is good approache. Please correct if i'm wrong.